# How to add unbound check box column to WinForms DataGrid (.NET 1.0, 1.1)?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagrid

How to add unbound check box column to databound DataGrid (WinForms .NET 1.0, 1.1)?

I cannot add fake column to the data source because it is data view coming from elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Why not adding the a checkbox column after you bound the datasource?

```
 // do this after changing dataGridView1.DataSource
 DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
 checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Selected";
 dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);
```

Comment: Hi Peter, ur snippet is straight to point.  
How to add a check box in the header of grid, so that one can select all the check boxes at once.

Comment: 1. Give the checkBoxColumn a name, to find it in the Columns later on by doint new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn("StatusCheck") 2. Add the checkbox on the UI, 3. Loop through all rows 4. Set row[i].Column["StatusCheck"].Checked = true/false;